# Promises with node.js and $q

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, promise

I got a simple app in node.js with mongoDB as the database.
I am trying to retrive one value from a collection, then do some adjustments to the data and then return it to the user.

I retrive the value from mongoDB, then i adjust it dynamically and i am able to see in debug mode that the new item is valid and holds the updated values.

But at the end of the flow when i am trying to return the value to the caller of the request something with the `deferred.resolve(appSettings)` aint working right.

I am being put into an endless loop. What i did manage to see while debugging is that i managed to catch an error (before the endless loop) in the controller

```
then(function (item) {
                res.Send(item);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                res.Status(400).Send(err);
            });
```

area, and it writes the following error message - `res.Send is not a function`.

The code :

uiSettings.service.js --

```
var config = require('config.json');
var dateUtil = require('date-and-time')
var Q = require('q');
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db(config.connectionString, { native_parser: true });
db.bind('UiAppSettings');

var service = {};

service.getOneByMappingType = getOneByMappingType

module.exports = service;

function getOneByMappingType(mappingType){
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    db.UiAppSettings.findOne(
        { MappingType: mappingType},
        function (err, appSettings){
            if (err) deferred.reject(err.name + ': ' + err.message);

            if(appSettings)
                adjustDates(appSettings);

            deferred.resolve(appSettings);

        });

        function adjustDates(appSettings){
            var defaultDates = appSettings.UiSettingsMap.FilterObject.Time.Defaults;
            for (var i=0; i< defaultDates.length; i++)
            {
                var startDate = calculateDate(defaultDates[i].StartDefaultsDate);
                var endDate = calculateDate(defaultDates[i].EndDefaultsDate);
                appSettings.UiSettingsMap.FilterObject.Time.Defaults[i].startDate = startDate;
                appSettings.UiSettingsMap.FilterObject.Time.Defaults[i].endDate = endDate;
            }
            appSettings.UiSettingsMap.FilterObject.Time.Selected.startDate = appSettings.UiSettingsMap.FilterObject.Time.Defaults[0].startDate;
            appSettings.UiSettingsMap.FilterObject.Time.Selected.endDate = appSettings.UiSettingsMap.FilterObject.Time.Defaults[0].endDate;

        }

        function calculateDate(dateData){
            let currDate = new Date();
            currDate = dateUtil.addYears(currDate, dateData.Year);
            currDate = dateUtil.addMonths(currDate, dateData.Month);
            currDate = dateUtil.addDays(currDate, dateData.Day);
            return currDate;
        }

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

uiSettings.controller.js ----

```
var config = require('config.json');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var uiService = require('services/uiSettings.service');

// routes
router.get('/:mappingType', getOneByMappingType)


module.exports = router;


function getOneByMappingType(req, res){
    uiService.getOneByMappingType(req.params.mappingType)
        .then(function (item) {
            res.Send(item);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            res.Status(400).Send(err);
        });
}
```

---- server.js

```
require('rootpath')();
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
var config = require('config.json');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// routes
app.use('/settings', require('./controllers/uiSettings.controller'));

// start server
var port = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 80 : 4000;
var server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Comment: The proper call is `res.send()` with a lowercase `s`, not `res.Send()`.  Javascript is case sensitive.  Same with `res.status()`.

Comment: So clear typo as actual problem aside, is there some reason you are applying an external promise library here? Or are you just reading and learning from very old blog posts? Because unless you are actually purposely use the "extras" of such libraries, then you probably get all you want from the built-in promise support in node.js. Unless of course you are actually forced to use an "ancient" version of node.js as well that is.

Comment: Same kind of query applies to mongoskin here as well. The reasons for such implementations historically was to add things in that the native driver was not delivering on. Modern releases of the native driver support promises right "out of the box" and do just about everything quite cleanly. You can even "plugin" your own choice of promise library if you really must. So now it's the abstractions like mongoskin that find themselves lacking these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jfriend00 commented the problem was caused by case sensitive usage of Send instead of send.

I also took Neil's advice and made many changes to use the built in native Promise and the native mongo driver instead.